# Hidden labels reappear when switching to satellite view

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've got a custom style applied to a Javascript Google Maps API (v3.20). I'm using a custom style which hides all labels except for roads and water. The labels hide properly when in Map view, but upon switching to satellite, the labels reappear permanently (unless you uncheck the checkbox under Satellite). Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

**Before**:

http://ss.kobitate.com/images/2015-06-11_1656.png

**After**:

http://ss.kobitate.com/images/2015-06-11_1659.png

Code:

```
function initialize() {

    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        minZoom: 14,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.421205,-81.782044),
        mapTypeId: "custom_map"
    }

    var styleOptions = [
        {
            featureType: 'all',
            elementType: 'labels',
            stylers: [
                { visibility: 'off' }
            ]
        },
        {
            featureType: 'road',
            elementType: 'labels',
            stylers: [
                { visibility: 'on' }
            ]
        },
        {
            featureType: 'water',
            elementType: 'labels',
            stylers: [
                { visibility: 'on' }
            ]
        }
    ];

    var styledMap = {
        name: 'Style Customization'
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)

    var customMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styleOptions, styledMap);
    map.mapTypes.set("custom_map", customMap);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the HYBRID map type available, remove it from the types available.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes

The following map types are available in the Google Maps API:

- MapTypeId.ROADMAP displays the default road map view. This is the default map type.
- MapTypeId.SATELLITE displays Google Earth satellite images
- MapTypeId.HYBRID displays a mixture of normal and satellite views
- MapTypeId.TERRAIN displays a physical map based on terrain information.

[Documentation on changing the MapTypeRegistry](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#MapTypeRegistry)

This will make only two buttons (Sat/yours) and remove the labels check box.

```
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    minZoom: 14,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.421205, -81.782044),
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE, "custom_map"]
    },
    mapTypeId: "custom_map"
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/o4k5bcd6/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initialize() {

  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    minZoom: 14,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.421205, -81.782044),
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE, "custom_map"]
    },
    mapTypeId: "custom_map"
  }

  var styleOptions = [{
    featureType: 'all',
    elementType: 'labels',
    stylers: [{
      visibility: 'off'
    }]
  }, {
    featureType: 'road',
    elementType: 'labels',
    stylers: [{
      visibility: 'on'
    }]
  }, {
    featureType: 'water',
    elementType: 'labels',
    stylers: [{
      visibility: 'on'
    }]
  }];

  var styledMap = {
    name: 'Style Customization'
  }

  map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)

  var customMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styleOptions, styledMap);
  map.mapTypes.set("custom_map", customMap);

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```

Comment: The map type selected is still showing as Satellite, but I will try changing the available types tomorrow.

Comment: You answer wasn't quite what I was looking for, as I was looking to use the Hybrid map but without the extra building labels. Your code did, however, lead me in the right direction. Thanks!